# Problema con visual studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Soy principiante en visual studio recien lo instalé esta mañana y no entiendo como puedo solucionar este problema descargué el paquete de c++ y cada vez que compilo me aparece esto:

> Error MSB8036 No se encontró la versión del SDK de Windows 8.1.

Instalé la versión requerida del SDK de Windows o cambié la versión del SDK en las páginas de propiedades de proyecto o haciendo click con el botón derecho en la solución y seleccionando "Redestinar solución"

Comment: tengo la version de windows 10

Comment: Hola Fernando, bienvenido a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [recorrido del sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Answer (score 0):

Ejecuta el visual studio installer, este permitirá modificar la instalación que has hecho ya sea agregando o quitando características, entre esas podrás seleccionar el Windows 8.1 SDK.